# ADA, Connect_Socket, dont work Timeout connection more 1 sec

Tags: sockets, ada, gnat

> `Connect_Socket(Socket, Address, Timeout => 2.0, Status => status);`
>
> `Put_Line("Selector " & Selector_Status'Image(status));`

Does not work, the program hangs in this place. If you set the timeout to 1 second, it works. How to make the delay more?

> `Set_Socket_Option (Socket, Option => (Name => Receive_Timeout, > Timeout => 1.0));`
>
> `Set_Socket_Option (Socket, Option => (Name => > Send_Timeout, Timeout => 1.0));`

Also, delays do not work, the program hangs. Read operation, bad
connection and close connection

Test procedure:

> ```
>  procedure start_client is              
>   Address  : Sock_Addr_Type;
>   Socket   : Socket_Type;
>   pck      : pck_ptr;
>   thred_r  : client_r;
>   thred_w  : client_w;
>   last     : integer;
>     status   : Selector_Status;
>
>
>    begin
>
>   pck := new packet_srv;
>   Address.Addr := Addresses (Get_Host_By_Name ("127.0.0.1"), 1);
>   Address.Port := 5910;
>   Create_Socket (Socket);      
>   Connect_Socket (Socket, Address, Timeout => 1.0, Status => status);
>   Put_Line("Selector " & Selector_Status'Image(status));
>   if status /= completed then
>      return;
>   end if;
>
>   thread_data.add_sock(socket);
>   thred_r.Start;
>   thred_w.Start;      
>
>   loop
>      Get_Line (pck.str, last);
>      pck.len := last;
>      pck.id := 0;
>      thred_w.send_data(pck.all);
>      exit when pck.str(1..4) = "exit";
>   end loop;
>   Close_Socket(Socket);
>  end start_client;
> ```

Comment: Test in Windows 8, GNAT 2017 and Windows 10 GNAT 2018

Comment: Need a [mcve], or can’t help.

Comment: It looks like your test procedure is missing the context clauses (`with` and `use` clauses at the beginning of the source file).  Also, which socket library are you using?